# Perl Module Installation From CPAN Failure

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install module [`Algorithm::SVM`](http://metacpan.org/module/Algorithm::SVM) from CPAN but I get the error listed below. At the message it says "failed". What may be the error?

```
*kadir@kadir-Inspiron-N5010:cpan install Algorithm::SVM
Reading '/home/kadir/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 07 Jan 2016 07:54:01 GMT
Running install for module 'Algorithm::SVM'

......

Makefile:350: recipe for target 'bindings.o' failed

make: *** [bindings.o] Error 1

  LAIRDM/Algorithm-SVM-0.13.tar.gz

  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK*
```

Comment: Is it this bug: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=43669 ? The module installs fine on my system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Debian go to the build location of the module(after you ran cpan Algorithm::SVM ):

```
sudo vim /home/youruser/.cpan/build/Algorithm-SVM-0.13-biHfmx/bindings.h
```

Add these two lines in this area:

```
using namespace std; 

#include <vector> 
#include <map> 
#include <assert.h> 
#include <cstdlib>         <=====  Add these
#include <string.h>        <=====  two lines
```

Save and exit and the rebuild the module from here:

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Test if the installation is successful:

```
sudo cpan Algorithm::SVM
```

Here is a more detailed explanation concerning this issue: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=43669